# Delay in website request when new dll is added

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

Every time I paste a new dll version of my project and request my website, it takes about 3 minutes for the request to return the page. What should I do?
I am using asp.net webforms.

Comment: yeap, that happens, but have to be only the first time

Comment: it happens every time i pase the project dll

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738490/asp-net-site-takes-a-while-to-load-after-restart/12738493#12738493

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every time there is an update happening in the bin folder, the application restarts and the worker process compiles the pages again.

Comment: This happens when i paste to my server,although when i use a virtual host no delay occurs!!

Comment: I would assume, there is nothing much running on your virtual host and  hence it is serving the app faster. Theoretically there should not be any difference between real server and virtual host.